# A Tab's page is not shown

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

A Tab's page is not shown.
I wrote PhotoController like

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class PhotoController:UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func PhotoSelect(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func PhotoSend(_ sender: Any) {
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

      private func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])

    {
        myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //myImageUploadRequest()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



  }
```

In this controller, my goal is to select photos and send them to server.
I am using TabbarController,but main storyboard which is connected with  PhotoController is not shown when I run emulator.I do not know why this happen,I think at least 2 buttons are shown in there.But 2 buttons are not shown.
However,ViewController is shown when I run emulator.
ViewController is

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webBrowser: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string:"https://www.google.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
        self.webBrowser.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

In this controller,Google web site is shown, and it is ok.
So,I think something connection is wrong, but I cannot find the point.
My Mainstoryboard is 
[Mainstoryboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmiw2.png)

Connection with PhotoController&mainstoryboard is
[Connection with PhotoController&mainstoryboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Iso7.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you set TabBarController as initial View Controller?

Comment: @SunilPrajapati yes